# Graviton-Dilaton Action for Kaluza-Klein in Polchinski (8.1.9)

Tags: string-theory, kaluza-klein

Polchinski uses the graviton-dilaton action (8.1.9) in his String Theory book
$$S_1= \frac{1}{2\kappa_0^2}\int d^D x\, \sqrt{-G} e^{-2\Phi} \left[ {R} + 4 \nabla_\mu\Phi \nabla^\mu \Phi \right]  \tag{8.1.9} $$
for the Kaluza-Klein theory. He then rewrites this in terms of the Kaluza-Klein fields as
$$S_1= \frac{\pi R }{\kappa_0^2}\int d^d x\, \sqrt{-G_d} e^{-2\Phi+\sigma } \left[ {R_d} -4\partial_\mu\Phi \partial\sigma + 4 \partial_\mu\Phi \partial^\mu \Phi-\frac{1}{4} e^{2\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} \right]   $$
I understand where most of this comes.  The integration over $x^d$ gives $2\pi R$. We have $ \sqrt{-G}= e^\sigma  \sqrt{-G_d}$. We use (8.1.8), i.e.
$$
 R  =   R_d  -2e^{-\sigma} \nabla^2 e^\sigma-\frac{1}{4} e^{2\sigma}  F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$
and we replace $\nabla_\mu \Phi$ by $\partial_\mu \Phi$ as $\Phi$ is a space-time scalar (I assume this is correct?).

But how does the $-2e^{-\sigma} \nabla^2 e^\sigma$ change into $-4\partial_\mu\Phi \partial\sigma $? What am I missing?

Comment: is metric signature mostly minus?

Comment: Polchinski is mostly positive

Comment: then scalar kinetic terms should have minus sign, namely the $\Phi$ kinetic terms. Misprint perhaps. Also I think the $-4\partial\Phi\partial\sigma$ should be $-4\partial\sigma\partial\sigma$.

Comment: @Kosm they provide a justification for the apparent wrong sign of the kinetic term in the paragraph after the equation. The mixed term seems to be legitimate but I have not found a justification.

Comment: @secavara I see now, I missed the dilaton factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you will excuse my quick scribbles (using ipad at the moment), here is something to try, let me know if it worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could I miss that?